# Real representation of $\langle \sigma_1,\sigma_2\rangle$ where $\sigma_i\in S_n$ are n-cycles

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

$S_n$ acts on $\mathbb{R}^n$ by permuting the coordinates, giving us the permutation representation. This representation can be decomposed into $\mathbb{R}^n=V\oplus W$, where $V$ is the trivial representation and $W$ is the standard representation.

Let $\sigma_1,\sigma_2\in S_n$ be an $n$-cycle, where $n$ is odd and prime. Is there any subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that is not $0,V,W$ or $\mathbb{R}^n$ that is invariant under the group generated by $\sigma_1,\sigma_2$?

Comment: You probably need to specify something more about how $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ sit inside $S_n$ relative to one another. For example if $\sigma_2 = \sigma_1^2$ then they just generate $\langle\sigma_1\rangle$.

Comment: I would be more interested in the case $\sigma_2\notin\langle\sigma_1\rangle$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a theorem of Burnside that says that a transitive subgroup $G$ of $S_n$ with $n$ prime is either solvable or doubly transitive (see [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0310200) for example).

In the solvable case, $G$ has a normal and hence unique Sylow $n$-subgroup, so this case arises when $\langle \sigma_1 \rangle = \langle \sigma_2 \rangle$, in which case $|G| = n$ and ${\mathbb R}^n$ is a direct sum of one subrepresentation of degree $1$ and $(p-1)/2$ of degree 2.

If $\langle \sigma_1 \rangle \ne \langle \sigma_2 \rangle$, then $G$ is not solvable, so it is doubly transitive, and then you are right in saying that ${\mathbb R}^n$ has only two irreducible subrepresentations (that is a standard result).